# Problem to configure virtualhost ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualhost

I'm facing some troubles to configure virtualhosts in ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to access the virtualhost domain on the browser it leads to the www folder.

Here is my virtualhost file in /etc/apache2/sites-enable/test:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName test.local.area
      ServerAlias teste.local.area
      DocumentRoot /var/www/git_pro/test
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtlm index.html index.htm index.shtml
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Here is the default site:

file: 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all 
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride all
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

And here is the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 Bruno-PC
127.0.1.2 test.local.area

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Someone to help me out here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename "test" to "test.conf".

Include rule in the main Apache2 config was changed from "*" in Precise to "***.conf" in Trusty.